# What is the limit of this function as x goes to minus infinity?

Tags: calculus, limits

I would like to compute the limit of:

$$\lim_{x\to -\infty} f(x)$$

where

$$ {f(x)=e^{-2x}(\cos(x)-\sin(x))}$$

My thought process was that since cosx and sinx are bounded between 1 and -1 and the exponential function goes to infinity the function will not converge. Is that correct and how can I prove it?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it will diverge.

Comment: Yes that is correct! To formally prove it show that for any $\epsilon>0$ you can find an $N\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $|f(x)|>\epsilon$ for all $x<N$.

Comment: Hint : look at the sign of $\cos(x)-\sin(x)$ and the graph of $\tan(x) - 1$. You may see why there is a problem with a potential limit of $+\infty$ or $-\infty$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If *diverge* is the logical negation of *converge*, then you are right. But if *diverge* means *divergent to infinity*, then I am sorry but you are wrong. The limit does not exist at all, as [WoframAlpha clearly shows](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5BExp%5B-2%20x%5D%20%28Cos%5Bx%5D-Sin%5Bx%5D%29,%7Bx,-50,-20%7D%5D).

For example, can you find a sequence $x_n \to -\infty$ such that $\cos x_n=\sin x_n$? Along this sequence, $f(x_n)=0$.
But you can easily find sequences $\{x_n\}$ such that $f(x_n) \to \pm\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

It is divergent:
$$
f(x)=\sqrt{2}e^{-2x}\cos(x+\frac{\pi}{4})
$$

The envelope of this function goes to infinity, but the function itself oscillates  between minus infinity and plus infinity.

Simply put: no limit!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is infinite.

put $y = -x$

$ \lim_{x \to -\infty} \implies \lim_{y \to \infty}$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it diverges.  Show that, for any $M<0$, there is an $N_1<M$ with $f(N_1)<-1$ and an $N_2<M$ with $f(N_2)>1$.  That means it can't settle down to a single value.